# Setting a pandas index or transposing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I imported a table with 30 columns of data and pandas automatically generated an index for the rows from 0-232.  I went to make a new dataframe with only 5 of the columns, using the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[data['Age'], data['FG'], data['FGA'], data['3P'], data['3PA']])
```

When I viewed the `df` the rows and columns had been transposed, so that the index made 232 columns and there were 5 rows.  How can I set the index vertically, or transpose the dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach is actually much simpler. You just need to pull out the columns simultaneously with a list of column names:

`df = data[['Age', 'FG', 'FGA', '3P', '3PA']]`

Answer (score 3):

Paul's response is the most preferred way to perform this operation. But as you suggest, you could alternatively transpose the DataFrame after reading it in:

```
df = df.T
```